# Need help with regex to extract strings from data into a hash [perl]

Tags: regex, perl, hash

I have a chunk of data from which I need to extract some strings and put them into a hash.
Would appreciate your help. I tried to do this with split command but it became too complicated.
Below is the example of what I would like help with.

```
 junk here
        name="bobby"
        team="orange"
    junk here
        name="steve"
        team="blue"
    junk here    
        name="joe"
        team="blue" 
junk here
```

Need to filter out junk from data. data->regex filter->hash

Hash I want: %hash= ('bobby' => 'orange',
         'steve' => 'blue',
         'joe' => 'blue',);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, assuming your values never contain quotes or any form of escaping, and `name=` is always the first thing on a line (except leading whitespace):

```
my %hash;

while ($string =~ /^\s*name="([^"]*)"\s*team="([^"]*)"/mg) {
  $hash{$1} = $2;
}
```

Comment: or just: %hash = $string =~ /^\s*name="([^"]*)"\s*team="([^"]*)"/mg;

Comment: MY HAT IS OFF FOR YOU. Perfect! This place needs an ability for people to donate money to contributors. (like a small paypal button next to their name) Thanks again! Perl rules!

Comment: @ysth, I think that's just a little _too_ concise for somebody who needed to ask the question in the first place.

Comment: I think using scalar context m//g only makes it more complicated, but I can see why you might disagree